# Custom IOC container - need help on 2/3 types

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

## Background

To help improve my understanding of IOC and how to use it, I want to create an example of all three IOC techniques: Constructor injection, Setter injection, and Interface injection without having to use a third party framework.  I think I have a basic example of constructor injection, but struggling with setter and interface injection.

## My Question

How would you approach tackling writing interface and setter injection from the ground up?

Here's my thoughts, let me know if I'm on the right track.

Interface injection:

1. Loop through resolved objects instantiated using constructor injection,check to see what interfaces are implemented in interfaceDependencyMap
2. Define some sort of interfaceDependencyMap to associate an interface to the implementation.
3. Resolve the implementation using interfaceDependencyMap
4. Assign the appropriate property to the object initialized with constructor injection

Setter injection:

1. Loop through resolved objects instantiated using constructor injection
2. Define some sort of setterInjectionMap
3. Resolve the expected parameter from MethodInfo using the constructor mappings
4. Call the setter method passing in the resolved parameter object

## Here's what I have so far for constructor injection

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        //instead of doing this:
        //
        //ICreditCard creditCard = new Visa();
        //var customer = new Customer(creditCard);
        //customer.Charge();


        var resolver = new Resolver();

        //map the types in the container
        resolver.Register<Customer, Customer>();
        resolver.Register<ICreditCard, Visa>();

        //because the customer constructor has an ICreditCard parameter
        //our container will automatically instantiate it recursively
        var customer = resolver.Resolve<Customer>();

        customer.Charge();

    }
}

public interface ICreditCard
{
    string Charge();
}

public class Visa : ICreditCard
{
    public string Charge()
    {
        return "Charging Visa";
    }
}

public class MasterCard : ICreditCard
{
    public string Charge()
    {
        return "Charging MasterCard";
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    private readonly ICreditCard _creditCard;

    public Customer(ICreditCard creditCard)
    {
        this._creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    public void Charge()
    {
        _creditCard.Charge();
    }
}


public class Resolver
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Type> dependencyMap = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return (T) Resolve(typeof (T));
    }

    private object Resolve(Type typeToResolve)
    {
        Type resolvedType = null;

        try
        {
            resolvedType = dependencyMap[typeToResolve];
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("could not resolve type {0}", typeToResolve.FullName));
        }

        var firstConstructor = resolvedType.GetConstructors().First();
        var constructorParameters = firstConstructor.GetParameters();
        if (constructorParameters.Count() == 0)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(resolvedType);

        IList<object> parameters = constructorParameters.Select(parameterToResolve => Resolve(parameterToResolve.ParameterType)).ToList();

        return firstConstructor.Invoke(parameters.ToArray());
    }

    public void Register<TFrom, TTo>()
    {
        dependencyMap.Add(typeof (TFrom), typeof (TTo));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can re-open this?

Comment: @EricRomanowski: See the reasons below as to why the question was closed; if you can address those reasons in your question, then others can vote to have it reopened, assuming they feel it meets the standards for questions on SO.

Comment: You can't, at least not directly. But if others (with high enough rep) think the edited answer is a real question now, they can vote to reopen. Or you could flag it for moderator attention with a custom message.

Comment: I reformatted and rephrased my question.  My apologies, I implied a question in the background information.

Comment: apparently this is c#'s best kept secret =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this kind of what you're looking for?

```
class Container
{
    class Registration
    {
        public Type RegistrationType;
        public Func<Container, object> Resolver;
    }

    List<Registration> registrations = new List<Registration>();

    public object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return registrations
            .First(r => type.IsAssignableFrom(r.RegistrationType))
            .Resolver(this);
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
    }

    public void Register<T>(Func<Container, T> registration) where T : class
    {
        registrations.Add(new Registration()
        {
            RegistrationType = typeof(T),
            Resolver = registration
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
interface IDependency
{
    string GetName();
}

class ConcreteDependency : IDependency
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Concrete Dependency";
    }
}

class ConstructorExample
{
    readonly IDependency dependency;

    public ConstructorExample(IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return "Consumer of " + dependency.GetName();
    }
}

class SetterExample
{
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }

    public string GetString()
    {
        return "Consumer of " + Dependency.GetName();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IDependency>(c => new ConcreteDependency());
    container.Register(c => new ConstructorExample(c.Resolve<IDependency>()));
    container.Register(c => new SetterExample() { Dependency = c.Resolve<IDependency>() });

    var constructor = container.Resolve<ConstructorExample>();
    Assert.AreEqual("Consumer of Concrete Dependency", constructor.GetString());

    var setter = container.Resolve<SetterExample>();
    Assert.AreEqual("Consumer of Concrete Dependency", setter.GetString());
}
```

If you want to get more advanced, I would recommend getting the source of any of these: [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/), [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), [Ninject](http://ninject.org/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was struggling the last three days trying to figure out how to write the generics for the interface and setter (not sure if that's the proper terminology).